# Adding Coordinates Dynamically to Google Maps Polygon

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps

I am currently retrieving a set of coordinates to construct a polygon on a Google map. Their documentation has coordinates set up this way:

```
// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
    var sampleCoords = [
      {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
      {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
      {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
      {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
    ];
```

How can those coordinates be added dynamically and passed as a variable?

I defined this array:

```
var poly_array = [];
```

and loop through my data to mirror the same format in the test example: **Note: the lat/lng vars have been defined in the full code.  This is just a snippet**

```
// Inner array with coords
$.each( mArray, function(k, iArray){

    poly_coordinates += '{ lat:';
    poly_coordinates += iArray[1];
    poly_coordinates += ', lng:';
    poly_coordinates += iArray[0];
    poly_coordinates += ' },';

});

// Push coordinates to array
poly_array.push(poly_coordinates);

// Build GMap
district_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center : { lat : lat, lng : lng},
               zoom : 15
    });

// Polygon
poly_border = new google.maps.Polygon({

    paths : poly_array,
    strokeColor : '#ff0000',
    strokeOpacity : 0.8,
    strokeWeight : 3,
    fillColor : '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity : 0.35
    });

    poly_border.setMap(district_map);   

// Style map
$('#map').css({ 'width': "100%", 'height': "400px"});
```

The result I get is an array that is surrounded by a pair of double quotes as shown in the **console**:

```
Array[0];
0: 
"{lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
 {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
 {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
 {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}"
```

This doesn't generate a polygon.  If I remove the double quotes and insert these values manually (as in the sample coordinates above) it works.

**How can I format the coordinates so that they are passed in as a variable and read correctly by the Polygon object?**

**Update**

I revised the code to include an array of JSON objects:

```
$.getJSON( osdb_url+upper_boundary+'?callback=?', function(i_upper){                        
    if( i_upper.shape && i_upper.shape.length > 0 ){

        $.each( i_upper.shape, function( i, oArray){

            $.each( oArray, function(j, mArray){

                // Inner array with coords
                $.each( mArray, function(k, iArray){
                  poly_array.push({ 'lat' : iArray[1], 'lng' : iArray[0] });
                });

            });

        });
    }                       
});
```

The coordinates are there, however, the polygon is still not being drawn. Here's a sample of what the console shows:

```
Array[0];
0:Object 
  lat: 25.774,
  lng: -80.190,
1:Object
2:Object
```

etc...

Comment: Why are you formatting it as a string if you want an array?

Comment: I was hoping to mirror the formatting of the coordinates as in the sample at the top of the page. What would be a better alternative to accomplish this?

Comment: Create the data as an array of JSON objects, not a string that looks like an array of JSON objects.

Comment: See update above.  JSON objects are in the array, but still no polygon.  Shouldn't the number of elements in the array not be 0?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates need to be passed as an array of LatLng objects.

```
poly_coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(iArray[1], iArray[0]);
```